# Change keyboard mapping (Input Source) from terminal in OS X

Tags: macos

I'd like to change the keyboard mapping from command-line (Terminal) in Mac OS X Lion (10.7).

I can manually set it (System Preferences -> Language & Text -> Input Sources), and there's a nice option that lets me use different input sources for different documents, but I'd like to bind it to a key under `zsh` to easily swap between Qwerty and Dvorak layouts (I'm learning Dvorak, and having the option to switch easily would be sensational).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the input sources are bound to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>(+<kbd>Shift</kbd> for reverse direction), which is the same as used by Spotlight (ask Apple why...).  Go into System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts tab > Keyboard and Text Input in the listbox on the left to select a different key sequence, or select Spotlight in that listbox to disable the Spotlight binding from shadowing the normal binding.